# Induce measure between topological spaces.

Tags: general-topology, measure-theory

Let $X$ and $Y$ be topological spaces, suppose that the function $f:X\rightarrow  Y$ is a continuous surjection. Let $\mu$ be a regular measure on $X$, and $M_X$ the set of $\mu$-measurable sets in $X$. We can induce a measure on $Y$ define in the $\sigma$-algebra $M_Y=\{A\subset Y: f^{-1}(A)\in M_X\}$ as 
$$\nu(A)=\mu(f^{-1}[A])$$

What conditions do we have to impose in order that the measure $\nu$ be regular?

I supposed that $\mu$ were regular but I got nothing.

Any clue?

Comment: Are there some particular conditions under which you want this to be true?

Comment: I know it is true if X is a string space with a Bernoulli measure,  Y is an associate self similar set and f is a kind of projection. But I don't know why is this true, I think is a more general fact that does not depend so strongly on the nature of X, Y and f. Maybe, it is enough if f is a quotient map or something like that (by the way in the example I mentioned f is indeed a closed map).

Comment: Different authors use different def'ns of regular measure. Is there one def'n you have in mind?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $A\in M_Y$. Then $$\nu(A)=\mu\big(f^{-1}(A)\big)=\sup\big\{\mu(K):K\subseteq f^{-1}(A),K \text{ compact}\big\},$$
since $\mu$ is regular. Now for $K\subseteq f^{-1}(A)$ with $K$ compact, $f(K)\subseteq A$ is compact too and $K\subseteq f^{-1}\big(f(K)\big)$. So $\nu\big(f(K)\big)=\mu\Big(f^{-1}\big(f(K)\big)\Big)\geq\mu(K)$ and $\nu$ is regular.